# What CP violating processes do we know of?

Tags: particle-physics, cp-violation, weak-interaction

So, after going over my particle physics notes and some introducing literature, it seems the currently known processes we experimentally confirmed to be CP violating are

- Kaon mixing (an indirect violation)
- Kaon decay (a direct violation)
- B meson decay (also a direct violation)

The Feynman graphs for Kaon mixing and B decay should be (note: these were made by me, that's why I ask) the following
[image: 2 of 3 CP violating processes as Feynman graphs]

Time in my plots goes from left to right. Now, do we suspect any other specific processes to be CP violating? Or are there some exotic ones my course eventually didn't cover because of time and complexity constraints?

Comment: The question of CP violation in neutrino mixing is still open (though the measurement of significantly non-zero $\theta_{13}$ by Daya Bay, Reno and Double Chooz leaves the door open for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CP violation has been found long time ago (in the 60's) in the neutral Kaon system and more recently in the neutral B mesons (your 4 diagrams). More interesting, is the situation with the neutral charm meson $c\bar{u}$. The LHCb experiment announced an evidence of CP violation in the charm sector in 2012 but the analysis of more data tends to reduce the magnitude of what was seen. You can read this article: http://cerncourier.com/cws/article/cern/52731. The experimental situation is not clear but with the new data of LHC run2 (starting this spring), it will be clarified.